# AG-Grid get page number with infinite scrolling

Tags: ag-grid

I'm using the AG-Grid infinite scrolling row model in Angular, by following the example from [Here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-infinite-scrolling/#example-server-side)

When running the above example, I can see in the developer tools that the page number gets logged out:

[image]

However I cannot seem to find a way to get the page number in my code. I've tried `paginationGetCurrentPage()`, however that doesn't appear to work with the infinite scrolling row model.

Is there any way to get the page number being requested when the getRows functions is fired? My api expects a page number to retrieve data, rather than a start and end row number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just simple math you need to do to get the page number inside `getRows`.

```
let pageNo = 1;
if (this.paginationPageSize != undefined)
   pageNo = params.startRow / this.paginationPageSize + 1;
// use pageNo to make API request
console.log('pageNo: ' + pageNo);
```

Check [this plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/IWKQdf9B5BcvepVYMLij?p=preview) I've created. Observe the browser logs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I initially thought if deriving the page number from the start and end row, but wanted to double check the library doesn't already provide a function for it. Thanks.